# Change App Switcher/Settings icon for PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have built an App for iOS using PhoneGap, PhoneGap Build and uploading it to iTunes Connect with Application Loader. When I open it in TestFlight, regardless of what I do to the code or images, the app icon in Settings and when you view it on App switcher (double tap the home button) is always the PhoneGap default robot (See image). If I search for .png's in the www directory this icon doesn't even exist! I have researched endlessly on how to configure my config.xml but nothing seems to change it and there doesn't seem to be any conclusive documentation to help me out.

[image]

Here is my config (sensitive information omitted) All urls to icons resolve correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "my_id_here"
        version   = "19">

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
        <string>1.0.0</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <name>App name here</name>

    <description>
        App description here
    </description>

    <author href="my_url_here" email="my_email_here">
        Author name here
    </author>

    <!-- Define the main entry-point to the application -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />       <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
        <preference name="target-device"              value="handset" />        <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
        <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
        <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
        <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
        <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="default" />    <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
        <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="false" />          <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />          <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
        <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
        <preference name="deployment-target"          value="8.0" />
    </platform>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status"      source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera"              source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture"       source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console"             source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts"            source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device"              source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion"       source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation"  source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"             source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"                source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer"       source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"         source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization"       source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"        source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media"               source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"        source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar"           source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration"           source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"           source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" />

    <gap:platform name="ios" />

    <!-- Define app icon and splashscreen for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <icon src="res/icon/ios/ipad-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/ipad-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

    <!-- app switcher & settings THIS IS WHAT I'VE GLEANED FROM WEB BUT IT DOESN'T WORK -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/AppIcon29x29.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/AppIcon29x29@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="87" height="87" />

    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="568" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
    <access origin="*" />
    <!--
       <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
       <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
       <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

</widget>
```

This article I found indicates it might be a PhoneGap build problem but the link at the bottom is now dead! [enter link description here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10914)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is posted here:

[What must I do to change default Phonegap icon when using the phonegap Build service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687909/what-must-i-do-to-change-default-phonegap-icon-when-using-the-phonegap-build-ser)

```
<icon src="res/icon.png" />
```